# XCODE 11 - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate window]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, xcode11, uiscenedelegate

Recently i updated to the XCODE 11 and came to know the concepts of SceneDelegate and AppDelegate . This is my simple code for in AppDelegate :

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return YES;
}
```

But unfortunately its getting crashed on the following line as shown in the Image:

[image]

And it shows the following error:

[image]

Please help me in resolving the issue which i am facing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can remove screen delegates if you want. If you need steps please let me know.

Comment: please do tell both ways .. removing scene delagates and to resovlve this error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Remove Screen Delegates:

Goto info.plist and remove the selected entry as shown below:
[image]

Delete ScreenDelegate.h and ScreenDelegate.m from the project:
[image]

Update your AppDelegate.h to:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window;

@end
```

And finally, remove the Screen delegates from the AppDelegates class:

[image]

Hope that helps.

If you want to use ScreenDelegates you can refer the answer from Asperi

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your root view controller's view is transparent, here is a place to setup `UIWindow` background color in your scenerio:

Modify in `SceneDelegate.m` the following callback as shown:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    if (scene.class == UIWindowScene.class) {
        [[(UIWindowScene *) scene windows].firstObject setBackgroundColor:UIColor.yellowColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: @FionaShoff, no, you cannot... and, btw, how this relates to topic question exception? ;)